# Getting elements of a command line and storing them into an array

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, archive

I am trying to implement the Unix command "tar" in C. It will be executed using the command `p5a -c archive infile1 infile2 ... infilek`  where the arguments infile1, infile2, ..., infilek
denote the names of the files which must be combined to create the archive. I am having trouble getting the file names from the command line and storing them into an array. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The filenames on the command line are *already in an array*.  You can access them from `argv`.  Can you explain your problem better?

Comment: argv stores all the arguments of the command line, i only want the ones starting at argv[3] all the way to the last input file. I don't know the total number of input files in advance. I need to store them so i can manipulate each of them to create my archive file.

Comment: `char **myarray = argv + 3;` and `int filecount = argc - 3;`, then.

Answer (score 0):

I really should not be spoon-feeding what looks like a homework question, but its been 2 years since I last touched gcc and need some practice.

On one hand, it looks like you are capable of using argc to get the data you want. The problem is 'how to know' the number of arguments. Most people use argv for that. Just made the following with Visual Studio 2010,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    int i = 1;
    printf("Your arguments are:\n");
    for (i=0; i<argv; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",argc[i]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

And here is some sample output (Win7 command line),

```
C:\...\Debug>C_hello.exe this is a string of input
Your arguments are:
C_hello.exe
this
is
a
string
of
input

C:\...\Debug>
```

I expect you'll get similar results with gcc in linux as well.

EDIT: Did some searching on the matter. Looks like there's a standard linux library for this sort of thing,
[getopt](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)

See the example on that page. Very well explained.